# Filtering a tibble in R by list of strings and returning all records that end with the strings in the list

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr, grepl

I have a huge data frame. One of the columns in the data frame is an email address.
In addition, I have a vector with domain extensions (for example: `c(".ac",".ad",".ae",".af",".ag",".ai")` - a total length of 259 extensions.)
I want to filter my data frame to contain records whose email ends with one of the strings in the extensions list.

I tried several options, but none of them produced the desired result.

```
df %>% 
  filter(endsWith(email, extensions))
```

```
df %>% 
  filter(stringr::str_ends(email, extensions))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression for pattern matching:

```r
ext <- c("ac","ad","ae","af","ag","ai")

df %>% 
  filter(grepl(sprintf("\\.(%s)$", paste(ext, collapse = '|')), email))
```

where the `sprintf` part creates a legitimate `regex` syntax like

```
"\\.(ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai)$"
```

Comment: why not: `email  %>% 
    filter(grepl(paste(extensions, collapse = "|"), email))`?

Comment: @TarJae In my sense `"\\.(ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai)$"` is the most standard `regex` syntax for this case. Your suggestion is merely `"ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai"`. I think it's a little loose for the OP's request.

Comment: I thought OP has a vector like `c(".ac",".ad",".ae",".af",".ag",".ai")`. :-)

Comment: @TarJae Then the regex could be `sprintf("(%s)$", paste0('\\', ext, collapse = '|'))`, or simply `paste0('\\', ext, '$', collapse = '|')`. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
email <- data.frame(
  email = c("you@something.ac", "her@business.ad", "not_valid@yahoo.com")
)

extensions <- c(".ac",".ad",".ae",".af",".ag",".ai")

email %>% 
  mutate(ext = paste0(".", sub('.*\\.', '', email))) %>% 
  filter(ext %in% extensions)
```